# Can someone please tell me why this if block is not working right?

Tags: android, string, if-statement, boolean-logic

Code:

```
String my = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ringtype"));
Log.e("my", my);
if(my=="default")
{
    Log.e(tablename, "button marked not visable1");
}
else
{
    Log.e(tablename, "button marked visable2");
}
```

LogCat:

```
07-28 02:10:57.396: ERROR/my(16204): default
07-28 02:10:57.404: ERROR/meds(16204): button marked visable2
```

I also tried `Log.e("my", "!"+my+"!");` to see if there was a hidden white space that was throwing it off. but there is not. as far as I can tell the two are a match and I should get the message that the button is not visible.

so I must be missing something but I can't figure out what it is
edit: thanks everyone, I'd accept all the answers as they make sense if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String can't be compared with ==
USe like `if(my.equals("default"))`

Answer (score 3):

**"my"** is different object and **"default"** is another one.. when you use **"=="** operator it compares the actual address/reference where as **".equals"** compares the content.. so use .equals

Answer (score 0):

try `my.equals("default")` instead of `my=="default"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `if(my.equals("default"))`